# Scala: split Map size n to List(Maps max size 3)

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

In:

```
Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2", "k3" -> "v3", "k4" -> "v4", "k5" -> "v5", "k6" -> "v6", "k7" -> "v7", "k8" -> "v8", "k9" -> "v9", "k0" -> "v0")
```

Out:

```
List(Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2", "k3" -> "v3), Map("k4" -> "v4", "k5" -> "v5", "k6" -> "v6), Map("k7" -> "v7", "k8" -> "v8", "k9" -> "v9), Map("k0" -> "v0"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val a = Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2", "k3" -> "v3", "k4" -> "v4", "k5" -> "v5", "k6" -> "v6", "k7" -> "v7", "k8" -> "v8", "k9" -> "v9", "k0" -> "v0")
a.grouped(3).toList
```

This gives you:

```
res2: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(k2 -> v2, k0 -> v0, k5 -> v5), Map(k9 -> v9, k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7), Map(k1 -> v1, k4 -> v4, k3 -> v3), Map(k8 -> v8))
```

The only thing it's not ordered

To keep the order you can do something like this:

```
a.toList.sortBy(_._1).grouped(3).toList.map(_.toMap)
```

Which gives you:

```
res6: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(k0 -> v0, k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2), Map(k3 -> v3, k4 -> v4, k5 -> v5), Map(k6 -> v6, k7 -> v7, k8 -> v8), Map(k9 -> v9))
```

Note that your initial `Map` is not sorted properly (the last element is "k0", but it should be the first one). But if you want to keep the insertion order and have the list of maps grouped by 3 this one should work:

```
val b = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2", "k3" -> "v3", "k4" -> "v4", "k5" -> "v5", "k6" -> "v6", "k7" -> "v7", "k8" -> "v8", "k9" -> "v9", "k0" -> "v0")
b.toList.grouped(3).toList.map(_.toMap)
```

This results to:

```
res8: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3), Map(k4 -> v4, k5 -> v5, k6 -> v6), Map(k7 -> v7, k8 -> v8, k9 -> v9), Map(k0 -> v0))
```